# Nullpointer when passing HTML canvas image to Controller method

Tags: java, javascript, html, playframework, playframework-1.x

I am trying to get a photo taken by a webcam in a canvas element uploaded to the server.
I am using Play Framework 1.2.5.3 and I have the HTML the following code:

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="180"></canvas> 
<button id="snap" onClick="testIT()">Snap Photo</button>
```

A form that is supposed to take the image in the canvas and upload it:

```
<form action="@{Drivers.addPhoto2}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="f1" id="dp" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

When clicking on the "snap" button the testIT() method is being called:

```
function testIT() {
window.alert("testing...");

var image = new Image();
var canvas = canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");

image.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
window.alert("varialbles created");

document.getElementById('dp').value = image;
window.alert("all done");
}
```

In the Controller it looks like this:

```
@Util
private static void addPhoto(Object driverPhoto) {
    System.out.println("addphoto statede");
    if (driverPhoto == null) {
        System.out.println("is null");
        //return;
    } else {
        System.out.println("not null");
    }

    System.out.println("is class: = " + driverPhoto.getClass());
    Driver driver = User.find("byEmail", Security.connected()).first();
    driver._save();
    index();
}

public static void addPhoto2(Object f1) {
    System.out.println("photo2 started");
    addPhoto(f1);
}
```

Now, when the "snap" button is hit, the picture is drawn (from webcam, this part works) and displayed in the canvas. Then the picture is supposed to be send to the INPUT in the form and from  there uploaded to the server where a new picture (type: Blob) is created and added to the driver.
What actually happens is: The picture is drawn in the canvas, and when I hit the upload button, the addPhoto2 method is called, but then I get a nullpointer exception in the addPhoto. Here the complete error message:

> Internal Server Error (500) for request POST /drivers/addphoto2
>
> Execution exception (In /app/controllers/Drivers.java around line 56)
>   NullPointerException occured : null
>
> play.exceptions.JavaExecutionException    at
>   play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:237)     at
>   Invocation.HTTP Request(Play!) Caused by:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   controllers.Drivers.addPhoto(Drivers.java:56)     at
>   controllers.Drivers.addPhoto2(Drivers.java:64)    at
>   play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeWithContinuation(ActionInvoker.java:557)
>     at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:508)    at
>   play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeControllerMethod(ActionInvoker.java:484)
>     at
>   play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeControllerMethod(ActionInvoker.java:479)
>     at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:161)    ... 1 more

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [Advanced bindings](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.7/controllers#binding) section of the manual, they note that uploaded files will be bound to a `File` object.

> File upload is easy with Play. Use a multipart/form-data encoded request to post files to the server, and then use the java.io.File type to retrieve the file object.

When I take your code and test it with the `f1` parameter of `addPhoto2` as a `File`, it works perfectly fine. With `f1` as `Object`, the parameter doesn't get set (and thus is `null`). I'm guessing the automatic Play parameter binding process gets confused when you specify a file parameter as an object and refuses to set it.

Comment: Thanks!
I just changed everything from Object to File, but I am still getting the same NullPointerException.

Comment: @Paperman If you get the exact same exception on the same line, something else must be going wrong, cause in my test application (made from the code you posted), that change fixed it. The only big difference between my test application and your code is that I commented the last 3 lines of `addPhoto`, since I don't have the model.

Comment: @Paperman I think the problem you're running into now is related to the JPA side of things. How do you add the photo to your model (I don't see it in the code here)?

Comment: I just realized that when the testIT() method is called the following line is not being executed: document.getElementById('dp').value = image;. Meaning that the value of the input element might actually be null. What I am trying to do with this line of code is to convert the image from the canvas into a file in the input element. How can I fix this?

Comment: @Paperman Ah, I focused on the Java side of things. As far as I know it is not possible (for obvious security reasons) to touch the value of an `input[type='file']` element. You could try using a hidden input field and send the data as binary or dateurl. Another way would be an ajax function to send the Blob straight to Play.